# Understanding appcompact values-v11/themes_base.xml errors

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I've just started a new android project on eclipse. As a project requirement, I've added appcompact-v7 support library into my android workspace.

As soon as the appcompat import completed, I get following errors in my eclipse console.

> [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\android_space\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:53 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat] D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>   [2014-11-15 17:41:54 - android-support-v7-appcompat]

I am aware that this error is within the `themes_base.xml` file in various values folders.

Please help me fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the v4 library as well and make sure you set both libraries up as [per these instructions](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res).

Comment: This didn't worked Jeff. Thanks for your kind reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your `android:minSdkVersion` on AndroidManifest.xml on appcompat_v7 project.

**AndroidManifest.xml on appcompat_v7**

Before:

```
android:minSdkVersion="7"
```

After

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

In my case, I've got the default value of android:minSdkVersion="7" and solved when I've changed to "8". Hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry I just saw your answer, the problem is fixed as I deleted all components of Android SDK and reinstalled. No problem as of now and I am not getting any errors.

Comment: @BigB, so you had to delete SDK v21 too?